# Does this site include questions relating to insurance, claims, the ACA etc?

Tags: discussion

Will this site include questions about health insurance? Claims, navigating the ACA etc?

Answer (score 6):

I would say **no**; insurance issues are a completely different area of expertise. Even highly-trained medical professionals employ insurance specialists to handle claims issues and anything to do with eligibility, etc. It is not really part of a site "for medical specialists, students, dietitians, and anyone with health-related questions."

Answer (score 2):

I would think that it *might*, and I emphasize *might* be on topic in very limited circumstances.

However, claims, ACA, eligibility, things like that would be not only highly specific to an individual, but would also vary company to company and contract to contract.

I can see someone making a case that resolving their insurance question/claim/dispute is key to maintaining their health, but that's about as far as I could stretch it. I just don't think that it's an answerable question for 99% of the cases.

Comment: If it is off topic in so many cases, would it be wise to give a blanket coverage of simply off topic?

Comment: @Tim - probably. I was leaving a caveat in case I missed something obvious. :)